# Use classic mode instead of styled mode in Highcharts with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am trying to not use styled mode in Highcharts and use classic mode instead. Documentation [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) says that classic mode is available on root and directly under each version folder on [code.highcharts.com.](https://code.highcharts.com/).

However, I am not importing anything from [code.highcharts.com.](https://code.highcharts.com/). I just use highcharts package I installed with npm,

```
    "highcharts": "^6.1.2"
```

With this version installed, Highcharts uses styled mode by default. How do I use classic mode in my Angular project instead? Thanks

Comment: I believe that if you put in your `angular.cli` your scripts & styles (the default, not the 'custom') it will works as you wish

Comment: If I try to add 'node_modules/highcharts/hightcharts.js' into scripts array, highcharts is throwing errors and page is not loading at all, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `classic` mode, you need to just import the files from the **root** of the package, just like that:

```
import Highcharts from `highcharts`
```

instead of:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/js/highcharts'
```

That's all.